# how to use the TRIM function in field calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator

I need to remove leading spaces in a field in my attribute table, but not how to do it from the field calculator

Comment: I try to do it with VBScript

Comment: VB: Trim([YourField])

Answer (score 10):

with python parser, you can use replace to remove ALL spaces

```
!myfield!.replace(" ","")
```

or, if you want to trim the first spaces only, you can use

```
!myfield!.lstrip()
```

Note that LTrim will work in vb

```
LTrim([myfield])
```